# How to add footnote at the beginning of each section in TOC beamer?

Tags: beamer, sectioning, footnotes

I have to present three papers in a presentation. I have my made a beamer presentation with three sections. At beginning of each section, the table of contents that shows the current section and its subsections.  **I want to add a footnote only at the beginning of each section to show where the work has been presented.** I also want that footnote not to be repeated. only one time at beginning of the section

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
  \usetheme{Madrid}
    \usecolortheme{beaver}
 \usepackage{utopia} 
 \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}

  \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\title[Title]{Title} 
 %\author{M. Saiful Bari\inst{1} \and Mr X\inst{2}} 
\author{My Name\inst{1}}
  \institute{
  \inst{1}
   Sample University testing and testing
   }

 \date{20 June, 2017}
     \begin{frame}{Table of Contents}
   \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
  \end{frame}




   \AtBeginSection[]
  {
   \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
   \tableofcontents[currentsection, 
  hideothersubsections, 
  sectionstyle=show/shaded,
   subsectionstyle=hide,
   ]
  \end{frame}
}



\AtBeginSubsection[]
  {
   \begin{frame}<beamer>
 \frametitle{Outline}
   \tableofcontents[
  currentsection,
  sectionstyle=show/hide,
 subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide,
]
  \end{frame}
 }


   \begin{document}
  \frame{\titlepage}
\section{Section A}
 \subsection{subsection A1}
   \subsection{subsection A2}
   \subsection{subsection A3}
    \subsection{subsection A4}
   \section{Section B}
      \subsection{subsection B1}
      \subsection{subsection B2}
     \subsection{subsection B3}
       \subsection{subsection B4}
        \section{Section C}
        \subsection{subsection C1}
       \subsection{subsection C2}
       \subsection{subsection C3}
       \subsection{subsection C4}



  \end{document}
```

Comment: I do not know if you still seek an answer, but IMHO the simplest way is to manually insert a `\footnotetext` in a frame containing the right `tableofcontents`